# Smooth scroll code

Tags: javascript, html, css

Having the following code structure, whats the code needed so the scroll is made in a smooth animated way?

I have a saved JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/v7qhzo8q/

The code is:

```
<nav id="nav">
 <ul id="top">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#vinedo">Viñedo</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#elaboracion">Elaboracion</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contacto">Contacto</a></li>
 </ul>
</nav>

<div id='vinedo' class="div1">
  Vinedo DIV
  <a href="#top">Back to top!</a>
</div>
<div id="elaboracion" class="div2">
  Elaboracion DIV
  <a href="#top">Back to top!</a>
</div>
<div id="contacto" class="div3">
  Contacto DIV
  <a href="#top">Back to top!</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.div1 {background:red;height:1000px;}
.div2 {background:green;height:1000px;}
.div3 {background:blue;height:1000px;}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo

Comment: Animated scrolling isn't something you just plop in with a few lines of code. Either you have to write something custom or use some kind of library. If you google "js smooth scroll" you'll get pages and pages of information.

Comment: If you want to scroll to next section in animated move, perhaps you need fullpage

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot.  It should do what you want if I'm understanding you correctly.  To change the amount of time it takes to scroll, simply change the number right before the return false code.  It is currently set to 600 milliseconds.

```
    $(function() {
      $('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function() {
        if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
          var target = $(this.hash);
          target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
          if (target.length) {
            $('html, body').animate({
              scrollTop: target.offset().top
            }, 600);  //change this number here to modify how long the scroll takes
            return false;
          }
        }
      });
    });
```

Comment: Yes, this solution does require jQuery.  Just link to that and it'll work great.

Comment: OP hasn't asked for jQuery, so don't provide jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Hi for a easy to use smoothscroll use the following link and just do the setup as explained in the Readme hope you come right.[Smoothscroll for Websites](https://github.com/galambalazs/smoothscroll-for-websites)